# Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell' to 'PFTableViewCell'

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

I'm trying to utilize `PFQueryTableViewController`, but for some reason I keep getting this error:

> Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell' (0x1105ccb80) to
>   'PFTableViewCell' (0x10e89e998).

I already associate the table cell with an identifier:

[image]

And here's the exception:

[image]

Thoughts?

Comment: Is the class of the custom cell set to `PFTableViewCell` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you change the class of the prototype cell to: PFTableViewCell ?

The identifier only helps you, well, identify the cell on the storyboard for the current table view.